# When using the mongodb $in query, the "(BadValue) $in needs an array" error occurs if [] uint8 is used for the query. Why?

Tags: mongodb, go, driver

everyone.When I use []uint8 array in mongodb $in query selector , "(BadValue) $in needs an array" error occurs.
Could someone give me some help? Thanks !!!

Here are my reproduction steps：

### Mongodb Info

mongodb driver version is v1.8.1

```
$ mongo --host 192.168.64.6
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://192.168.64.6:27017/
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("e4d7cea2-ab81-45ad-a51e-e7acf45a7242") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.8
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match

mongos> use testing
switched to db testing
mongos> db.numbers.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee62032"), "type" : 0, "value" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee62033"), "type" : 1, "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee62034"), "type" : 2, "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee62035"), "type" : 3, "value" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee62036"), "value" : 4, "type" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee62037"), "value" : 5, "type" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee62038"), "type" : 6, "value" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee62039"), "type" : 7, "value" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee6203a"), "type" : 8, "value" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b71d3d73b251bceee6203b"), "type" : 9, "value" : 9 }
```

### Go Code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

func main() {
    // init mongodb client
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://192.168.64.6:27017/"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // mock some data
    collection := client.Database("testing").Collection("numbers")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        _, err = collection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{"type": uint8(i), "value": i})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }

    // query
    filter := bson.M{"type": bson.M{"$in": []uint8{1, 2, 3}}}
    res := collection.FindOne(ctx, filter)
    if err = res.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

### Result

When I start the command on the command line, I get the following output：

```
go run main.go

(BadValue) $in needs an array
```

Comment: mongodb driver version is v1.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uint8` is an alias to `byte`, and `[]byte` is a special type, it's handled differently than other slice types (not as a slice of numbers). `[]byte` values are encoded using [`bsoncodec.ByteSliceCodec`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.1/bson/bsoncodec#ByteSliceCodec) and other slice values are encoded using [`bsoncodec.SliceCodec`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.1/bson/bsoncodec#SliceCodec).

Use a slice of any other number type, e.g. `[]int8` or `[]int`:

```
filter := bson.M{"type": bson.M{"$in": []int{1, 2, 3}}}
```

Note: the mongo driver has its own BSON implementation and package, do use that: [`go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.1/bson). In your example you are importing and using `gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson` which is a completely different BSON implementation, developed as part of the `mgo` driver (now unsupported and obsolete). Do not mix different drivers.

Comment: Thank You! use  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson" also occurs  "(BadValue) $in needs an array​".  I would use uint32.

Comment: @sinksmell Yes, it's the same error. I suggested to use the BSON implementation from the mongo driver you're using, for simplicity and  consistency, not to avoid that error. The fix for the error is to use another slice type, not `[]uint8`, this is all in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove conversion of `i` to `uint8`, and for getting data correct code like this.

```
// mock some data
collection := client.Database("testing").Collection("numbers")
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    _, err = collection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{"type": i, "value": i})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}

 res := collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{
    "type": bson.M{
        "$in": []int{1, 2, 3},
    },
})
if res.Err()!=nil{
        // handle error
}
```

Then you can get data as raw or decode into another type, like:

```
 res.DecodeBytes()
```

Comment: Thank You ! In my collection, some data stored in uin8 format. I want use $in and []uint8. It is true that replacing uint8 with other types can solve the problem, and we have also used this method to solve the problem, but the root cause is not yet known.